# Close sidebar then process form submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my Google Spreadsheet, the user can click a custom menu item that brings up an HTML form in the sidebar so they can enter data. The function that processes that form data takes ~25 seconds to complete. **Is it possible to close the sidebar THEN process the form data?** It's annoying for the user to have part of the screen blocked for half a minute while the script finishes.

Currently I'm calling this function from `<form onSubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">` and as expected the sidebar only closes after the script is finished:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.close).processForm(formObject)
  }
```

**Edit**
I tried @Jack_Brown's strategy of adding a sleep delay and unfortunately "setTimeout" is not available in Apps Script. Also, I don't think the "async" function declaration is available in Apps Script either.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`google.script.host.close()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close()) right after you call `google.script.run.processForm(formObject)` to close your sidebar. As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run),

> google.script.run is asynchronous client-side JavaScript API

Which, means javascript on the client side doesn't wait for the execution to be over before proceeding to the next line in the code. Hence, you can call  `google.script.host.close()` right after the run API. Like so

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject)
  google.script.host.close()
  }
```

Since you are closing the client side prematurely, you dont need a successHandler.
**Note:** However, you will get no notification if the run fails!

**Edit:** The call to the `google.script.host.close()` right after the call to run, seems to affect the asynchronous call. However, adding delay allows it to complete the API call before closing the sidebar. The below function sleeps for 2 seconds before closing the sidebar.

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject)
    setTimeout(google.script.host.close, 2000)
  }
```

Reference: 
[`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does a great job of closing the sidebar immediately but the processForm function never finishes! The value I expect to see change on the spreadsheet never changes. It's as if closing the sidebar interrupts the running function? Any ideas?

Comment: I added a sleep function before the call to host.close() that seems to resolve the issue. Tested in chrome.

Comment: Check out my edit above. I tried calling `setTimeout` but it is not available in Apps Script. Are you testing in the script editor?

Comment: @JamesNicholson setTimeout is a function in javascript i.e your client side. The above code needs to be in your HTML page

Comment: Yes I know that, but even the HTML is not run directly by the client browser. That's why certain things aren't available, like DOM manipulation. See [this page in Apps Script docs] (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features). Are you testing in the Apps Script editor or in some other javascript console?

Comment: I am running this code in apps script editor. HTML is run directly by the client browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166784/discussion-between-jack-brown-and-james-nicholson).

Comment: Read the above chat for more details on the solution. For some reason I needed to have <base target=“_top”> in the <head> of my html file.